# Python: make every instance have a different superclass

Tags: python, metaclass

In Python, I currently have instances of a class like `MyClass('name1')`, `MyClass('name2')` and so on.

I want to make it so that each instance has its own superclass, i.e., I want `MyClass('name1')` to be an instance of `Name1MyClass` and `MyClass('name2')` to be an instance of `Name2MyClass`. `Name1MyClass` and `Name2MyClass` would be dynamically generated subclasses of `MyClass`. I can't figure out how to do this, because it seems that Python always makes whatever is returned from `__new__` an instance of that class. It isn't clear to me how to do it in a metaclass either.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to define `__doc__` docstrings on the instances. But it seems that `help` completely ignores `__doc__` on instances; it only looks on classes. So to put a different docstring on each instance, I need to make each instance have its own custom class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think you want a metaclass here.  `__metaclass__`es are used when the class is created, not when you call the class to construct a new instance of the class (or something else).

Here's an answer using `__new__` without a metaclass.  It feels a bit hacky, but it seems to work:

```
_sentinel = Ellipsis
class MyClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, name):
        if name is _sentinel:
            return object.__new__(cls)
        else:
            instance = type(name + cls.__name__, (MyClass,), {})(_sentinel)
            # Initialization goes here.
            return instance

print type(MyClass('name1'))
print type(MyClass('name2'))
```

There's a catch here -- All the business logic of initializing then new instance must be done in `__new__`.  Since `__new__` is returning a different type than the class it is bound to, `__init__` won't get called.

---

Another option is to create a class factory:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

def class_factory(name):
    new_cls = type(name + MyClass.__name__, (MyClass,), {})
    return new_cls() # Or pass whatever you want in here...

print type(class_factory('name1'))
print type(class_factory('name2'))
```

Finally, you could even create a non-`__new__` class method:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def class_factory(cls, name):
        new_cls = type(name + cls.__name__, (cls,), {})
        return new_cls() # Or pass whatever you want in here...

print type(MyClass.class_factory('name1'))
print type(MyClass.class_factory('name2'))
```

Comment: I think instead of checking for a sentinel, you can just check which class `cls` is.

Comment: Furthermore, to work with subclasses, you should use `(cls,)` as the bases argument to `type`, not `(MyClass,)`.

Comment: @asmeurer -- Sure, you can do it however you want.  I don't know your use-case, so I'm not sure how to best design my answer.  But I think that all the pieces are there for you to build it out however you want.

Comment: Well it doesn't really matter what my use-case is. You should always write classes in such a way that subclasses work.

Comment: @asmeurer -- Fair point, but it's unclear *how* you want subclasses to work.  Since your class is technically returning instances of a different type of class, It's hard to say what the actual subclassed behavior *should be*.  In any event, the code above isn't meant to be production ready anyway -- Hard-coding the class in my mind conveys the *idea* of what is happening and de-mystifies it to some extent.  My purpose is to write clear easy to understand code to convey an idea -- Not to write production ready code.

Comment: OK, mystery demystified. Here is my use-case https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/2538.

Comment: By the way, in case anyone is wondering, these instances are going to be totally unpicklable.